Dynamic width horizontal Collection view using compositional layout
I am trying to create a collection view that has a simple cell with text, which means that the width and height of the cells should be dynamic. Since it should be able to be shorter/longer and the number of lines is n (Text comes from the service). As long as The cells width is not bigger than the collection it self, there is no problem. But if a long text should be presented it crashes.
It would only happen using .estimate as size, it wont if the cell take all the possible space
This is how the implementation looks like
Error:
Thread 1: "<UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x105b08470> ran into an error when computing the layout for section at index 0 in container <_UICollectionLayoutContainer: 0x600001756440 contentSize={353, 500}; contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}}>. Container calculated by applying insets ({0, 0, 0, 0}) from sectionInsetsReference \"safeArea\" to collection view frame {{0, 0}, {353, 500}}.\nError: NSCollectionLayoutItem created with invalid combination of spacing and size specified. This group cannot fit even a single item. Inspect the spacing and size of the items in this group and ensure that they fit into the group when its effective size is {333, 480}.\nGroup: <NSCollectionLayoutGroup 0x6000035082c0 size={.containerWidthFactor(1), .estimated(480)}>\n\t layoutDirection: .horizontal\n\t interItemSpacing=.fixed(4)\n\t subitems=\n\t\t <NSCollectionLayoutItem 0x600002620660 size={.estimated(32), .estimated(120)}>"
The collectionView is inside a UIView that works as wrapper and the view is inside a StackView like this:
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(collectionViewWrapper)
        stackView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionViewWrapper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let actionGruopViewHeight = collectionViewWrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            collectionViewWrapper.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor),
            actionGruopViewHeight
        ])
        view.backgroundColor = .red

        collectionViewWrapper.didLayoutAction =  {
            actionGruopViewHeight.constant = collectionViewWrapper.collectionView.contentSize.height
        }


CollectionView wrapper:
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(ActionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ActionCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
        addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])


CollectionViewLayout:
    private lazy var layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [weak self] _, _ in
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(32), heightDimension: .estimated(120))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(480))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(4)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = .init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 4
        return section
    }

Cell:
    private lazy var textLabel: UILabel = {
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        return textLabel
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .gray
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

Did I do something wrong? is there a fix/workaround to avoid the crash?
Notice that it would be easy to reproduce with accessibility font sizes, since usually it would need 2 lines

A label can only wrap its text when it has a limited width ... so I don't think this approach is going to work for you. Also, it's not entirely clear what your layout goal is... if you want the cell to wrap if the text is too long, is this what you're expecting? https://i.sstatic.net/V3yPG.png

@DonMag The idea is to get a layout like the first option in the image you linked that is able to adjust to every size font and be a11y compliant,

@DonMag May I also ask you what is the difference between both examples?

The question is: Do you want it to always wrap onto the next "row" if it doesn't fit between the current label and the right edge, like this: https://i.sstatic.net/Avsbt.png --- or, do you want it to wrap on the same row like this: https://i.sstatic.net/TPsua.png
